# Reloading a sound using OpenAL

Tags: c++, c, audio, openal

I have successfully loaded and played a sound clip but want to update it from disk while the application is running. I'm calling alBufferData again for my clip but get Invalid Operation error. Both old and new sound clips are valid and work in isolation, it's only the reloading that fails. How can I reload sound data for a clip? I'm using OpenAL on OS X but remember having the same problem also on Windows with OpenAL-soft.

Comment: Why the downvotes? On the other hand, I was able to solve this by calling `alSourcei( srcID, AL_BUFFER, 0 );` before calling `alBufferData` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `alSourcei( srcID, AL_BUFFER, 0 );` before `alBufferData()` solved the problem.